# How does Jenkins one-at-a-time hash output have fixed length since it doesn't use mod system?

Tags: hash

I understand how algorithms like SHA and MD5 always have fixed output for n-length string as they use a mod system, how does jenkins hash achieve this using just bitwise operators? Any help appreciated (links, in depth explanations).

```
uint32_t jenkins_one_at_a_time_hash(char *key, size_t len)
{
  uint32_t hash, i;
    for(hash = i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
        hash += key[i];
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    return hash;
}
```